# Moving MP3 files from one directory to another using regex

Tags: python, algorithm, regex

This is a simple script for moving my MP3 files from one directory to another. I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way to handle my task in the script. I analyzed the algorithm to be \$O(n^2)\$.

```
import os
import shutil
import re

files = os.listdir(os.path.dirname('/home/rich/Downloads/'))

regex = r"(.mp3)"

for f in files:
    if (re.search(regex, f)):
        f = os.path.join('/home/rich/Downloads/', f)
        shutil.move(f, '/home/rich/Music/Songs/')
```

Comment: You could do a benchmark and compare the solution against using [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html). However, it hardly seems a performance-critical script.

Comment: How did you arrive at O(n^2)? You only have one loop.

Comment: I thought that the search for ".mp3" for each file with regex took O(n) time as well.

Comment: Performing a constant (\$k\$) number of operations on each file brings to complexity to \$O(kn)\$. For it to have been \$O(n^2)\$, you would have needed to loop through all files each and every time you needed to perform an operation on one of them.

Comment: hmm. I miss understood that then. I didn't think that the regex search was a constant operation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Constants like `'/home/rich/Downloads/'` could be made into variables, for example:

   ```
   src_dir = '/home/rich/Downloads/'
   dest_dir = '/home/rich/Music/Songs/'
   ```

   This would make it clear what they mean, and would avoid duplication if you need to use a constant more than once.
2. There are three problem in the regular expression.

   First, the parentheses are unnecessary — they *capture* whatever they match for future use, but there's no future use here.

   Second, the dot has a special meaning in regular expressions — it matches any character. If you want to match a literal dot, then you need to escape it.

   Third, the regular expression is not *anchored* and that means it can match anywhere in the string. For example, it will match the filename `"not.actually.an.mp3.wav"`.

   The regular expression should be `r"\.mp3$"`.
3. There's no need for a regular expression at all, you could just call [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to get the extension:

   ```
   for f in files:
       _, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
       if ext == '.mp3':
           shutil.move(f, dest_dir)
   ```
4. In fact there's no need to do that, because you could use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) instead:

   ```
   for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(src_dir, '*.mp3')):
       shutil.move(f, dest_dir)
   ```
5. It seems like overkill to use Python for this, because it would be a one-liner in shell:

   ```
   mv ~/Downloads/*.mp3 ~/Music/Songs/
   ```